# Firefox CSS Error - "Skinny Width"

Tags: html, css, firefox

Chrome, IE & Safari are all displaying the code as intended. However, Firefox is providing "Skinny Columns" for any text no wrapped in 'p' Tags.

However it does display right using the Media Query at smaller widths. Perhaps is has something to do with the Margin and Padding on the .event-container class.

[Here's a Screen Show of a page viewed in Firefox.](https://gunshowtrader.com/media/firefox-skinny-columns.png)

[Here's the JS Fiddle Page.](http://jsfiddle.net/a8bo6qcj/3/)

HTML:

```
<article class="event-container">
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title" itemprop="name">TITLE</h1> 
        <p class="entry-meta">META INFO</p>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="event-wrap">    
            <div class="event-row">
                <div class="event-column event-label">COL 1</div>
                <div class="event-column event-text"><p class="first">Here's some text for Column 2. Lots of Text Here.</p><p>Here's some more text and this displays properly in Firefox.</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="event-row">
                <div class="event-column event-label">LIST</div>
                <div class="event-column event-text">
                    <ul>
                        <li>LIST ITEM</li>
                        <li>LIST ITEM</li>
                        <li>LIST ITEM</li>
                        <li>LIST ITEM</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.event-container {
    display: table;
}

.event-container ul, 
.event-container ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

.event-container p {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.event-container p.first {
    padding: 0;
}

.event-container .event-wrap {
    float:right;
    width:100%;
    margin-left: -180px;
    padding-left: 180px;
}

.event-container .event-wrap .event-row {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.event-container .event-wrap .event-row .event-column {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.event-container .event-wrap .event-row .event-column.event-label {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.event-container .event-wrap .event-row .event-column.event-text {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.event-container .ad {
    float: left; 
    width: 160px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .event-container .ad {
        float: left; 
        width: 160px;
    }

    .event-container .event-wrap {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    .event-container .event-wrap, 
    .event-container .event-wrap .event-row .event-column, 
    .event-container .event-wrap .event-row .event-column.event-label, 
    .event-container .event-wrap .event-row .event-column.event-text {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        clear: both;
    }

    .event-container .event-wrap .event-row {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .event-container .event-wrap .event-row .event-column {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The HTML and CSS you provided is not helpful to figuring out what is going on with your columns. Either provide more relevant code or make a JS.Fiddle reproducing your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Added [JS Fiddle Page.](http://jsfiddle.net/a8bo6qcj/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I see whats going on. It seems that the 'event-row' columns are overlapping when the screen size gets too small. In order to stack them you will need to remove the float for this CSS (line 1519)

```
.event-container .event-wrap .event-row, .club-container .club-wrap .club-row, .vendor-container .vendor-wrap .vendor-row {
    display: block;
/*Removed
    clear: both;
    float: left;
*/
}
```

Removing that code seems to display the columns correctly in Firefox. If you want this to only trigger when are at a specific screen size you will need to wrap it in a `@media` call. Hope that helps.